# I don't understand how pointers work in this code?

Tags: c, pointers

I don't understand this part of the code below. I mean `alloc_MY_CAR()` returns some array and how does `&` work so that `newTab->pFunFree = &free_MY_CAR` sees this array which `newTab->pDat` returns?

I don't understand pointers well. I only know that `&` store address of variable and `*` is a pointer or a value of the variable.
Could anyone guide me on how to use it properly and how does it work? I'm a  beginner, so don't be so hard on me.

Thanks in advance!

```
#pragma once
struct MY_CAR {
    char *model;
    int year;
};


void print_MY_CAR(void* pdata);
void free_MY_CAR(void *pdata);

MY_CAR* alloc_MY_CAR();



    switch (typ) {
        case 0:
            newTab->pDat = alloc_MY_CAR();
            newTab->pFunFree = &free_MY_CAR;
            newTab->pFunPrint = &print_MY_CAR;
            break;
    }
    MY_CAR* alloc_MY_CAR() {
        MY_CAR* tab = (MY_CAR*)calloc(1, sizeof(MY_CAR));
        if (!tab) {
            exit(0);
        }
        else {
            char model[125];
            printf("Podaj model: ");
            scanf("%s", model);
            tab->model = (char*)calloc(strlen(model) + 1, sizeof(char));
            strcpy(tab->model, model);
            printf("Podaj rok: ");
            scanf_s("%d", &tab->year);
        }
        return tab;
    }
void free_MY_CAR(void *pdata) {
    MY_CAR* car = (MY_CAR*)pdata;
    if (!car || !car->model) return ;
    free(car->model);
    free(car);
}
```

Comment: "*newTab->pDat returns some array*" - No, there is no function call here, so there is nothing to be returned. `pDat` cannot be an array because you can't assign to arrays. It's probably a pointer.

Comment: Looks like this is pointer to functions. Perhaps not the easy way to start C.

Comment: It seems that the code is assigning pointer to functions, in this case `&free_MY_CAR` and plain `free_MY_CAR` are the same (the address of operator doesn't affect the assignment)

Comment: I assume free_MY_CAR and print_MY_CAR are functions, so, it's a function pointer : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-pointer-in-c/

Comment: I meant alloc_MY_CAR sorry

Comment: You don't undestand me.

Comment: This is part of some larger program and it matters what the rest of the program says. But it seems to me this is someone trying to use C to do things that C++ was designed to do, in particular creating an interface that supports polymorphism of the objects that implement it.

Comment: alloc_MY_CAR()  returns some array of car: its model and year. And then function  &free_MY_CAR free all data in this array returned by alloc_MY_CAR() . So, function &free_MY_CAR "see"  this array  and then free this array. But how does it work? Why?

Comment: As for how the functions can "see" `newTab->pDat`: we don't know, you have to show us the parts of the code where they do that so we can explain them. It could be that `alloc_MY_CAR()` creates a singleton that the other functions access, or it could be that `newTab->pDat` is passed as an argument to those functions.

Comment: 1. EDIT the question to add information, don't expect people to read all these comments. 2. SHOW us, don't tell us. As a beginner, you don't know how to describe the code so that we can reconstruct how it actually works. We have to see the actual lines of the code of those functions.

Comment: OK, that's enough to get started, I think.

Comment: I don't understand how 'pdata ' works - I assume that this is a data of car, but I don't know in which way &free_MY_CAR sees it. I know that newTab->pFunFree = &free_MY_CAR point on function , but whence this have array of car's data?

Comment: @KasiaIks It doesn't. You'd have to check how `pFunFree` is used, but in and of itself it knows nothing about `pData`.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the function `free_MY_CAR` has an argument of type `void*`,
a pointer to a "void" type
(which is a C idiom for a pointer to something without telling the type of the thing pointed to),
and the first thing it does is to reinterpret that pointer as a pointer to a `MY_CAR`.

So the function is probably intended to be called like this:

> newTab->pFunFree(newTab->pDat);

That is, the way the functions "know" what pointer was returned by 
`alloc_MY_CAR()` and stored in `newTab->pDat`
is that the programmer explicitly **tells** the functions what pointer
is stored in `newTab->pDat`.

The advantage of doing such things is that it allows some code to do some operation on a data structure without necessarily having to know what kind of data structure it will actually operate on when the program actually runs.
In the call to `pFunFree` above, `newTab` could have been initialized by the `case 0` code shown in the question, but there could be another case
that initializes it with `alloc_MY_JOB()`, `&free_MY_JOB`, and `&print_MY_JOB`,
where the `MY_JOB` functions allocate/free/print a data structure that is quite different from the data structure used by 
`alloc_MY_CAR()`, `&free_MY_CAR`, and `&print_MY_CAR`.
Then if you call

> newTab->pFunPrint(newTab->pDat);

we might not be able to predict when we write the code whether it will print the contents of a data structure created by 
`alloc_MY_CAR()` or by `alloc_MY_JOB()`;
but we *can* predict that it will print the detailed information it has
about your car, or your job, or whatever was read from the data file and stored in `newTab`.

The property that we can make a function call that uses a data structure in a way appropriate to that data structure, without having to know when we write the code what the type of data structure will be, is called
**polymorphism**.

This is a cumbersome idiom and there are lots of ways to get it wrong.
One of the selling points of C++ is to enable people to write polymorphic objects more easily than this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Things are much understandable to me now ;)

Comment: Dereferencing function pointers is pointless (functions always immediately decay back to pointers). You can just do `newTab->pFunFree(newTab->pDat);`.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for the tip, haven't actually needed this technique in years since I switched to C++.

Comment: So, that's the my professor's point.. He told us that our code should be universal - like you have just written - it must be working even though we will change a type of structure.

Comment: Could you tell me why solution (*newTab->pFunFree)(newTab->pDat) is bad? What is diffrence between newTab->pFunFree(newTab->pDat)?

Comment: What does exactly mean "dereferencing"?

Comment: It is associated with more operations that program must do by  (*newTab->pFunFree)(newTab->pDat)?

Comment: "Derferencing" is what `*` does: it causes the program to see the thing that is pointed at, rather than just the pointer. I think melpomene's point was that there is no difference between `(*newTab->pFunFree)(newTab->pDat)` and `newTab->pFunFree(newTab->pDat)` because in the end the compiler will do the same thing either way, in one case because you explicitly said to do so and in the other because it was going to do it anyway.